# Problem getting the right values using component react-bootstrap/Modal

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am building a React-App and I have a a problem with the use of components in my React-App. When i work with components like buttons or tables everything works, but when i use a modal there are problems. My serverside json looks like

```
let jsonlist = [
    {
        Title: "first title",
        Listofitems: ["Item 01", "Item 02", "Item 03"]

    },
    {
        Title: "second title",
        Listofitems: ["Item 04", "Item 05", "Item 06"]

    }
]
```

and I work with it on clientside like

```
import { React, useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal';

const ModalList = ({ socket }) => {
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
    const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
    const handleShow = () => setShow(true);
    const [lists, setlist] = useState([]);
    const fetchFact = () => {
        fetch("http://myapi/getList")
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((data) => setlist(data));
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        fetchFact()
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className='container'>
            {lists.map(singleobject => (
                <div>
                    <div>{singleobject.title}</div>
                    <div>{singleobject.listofelement.join(', ')}</div>
                    <div>
                        <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleShow}>
                            {singleobject.title}
                        </Button>
                        <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
                            <Modal.Header closeButton>
                                <Modal.Title>{singleobject.title}</Modal.Title>
                            </Modal.Header>
                            <Modal.Body>{singleobject.listofelement.join(', ')}</Modal.Body>
                            <Modal.Footer>
                                <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClose}>
                                    Close
                                </Button>
                                <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleClose}>
                                    Save
                                </Button>
                            </Modal.Footer>
                        </Modal></div>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}

export default ModalList;
```

When i work with components like `react-bootstrap/Accordion` or `react-bootstrap/Table` evrything works fine and I can use/acess the right values for `singleobject.title` and `singleobject.listofelement`. The `singleobject.title` inside the `<Button>` gets the right value (the first button displays `first title` and the second button displays `second title`). But when I use `singleobject.title` and `singleobject.listofelement` in the `Modal` both modals get as `title` `second title` and as `singleobject.listofelement` both times `["Item 04", "Item 05", "Item 06"]`. Even if I increase the number of elements in the list, the values of the last object in the json are always used/displayed. What can I do that every element gets displayed just once like when i use `react-bootstrap/Accordion` or `react-bootstrap/Table`.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

All modal components use the same single `show` state, so when you toggle any modal shown they all are shown and the last one rendered is highest in the DOM regarding view order.

## Solution

Use a `singleobject` id or some other unique property to specify showing a specific modal.

Example:

```
const jsonlist = [
  {
    id: '1', // <-- add id property
    Title: "first title",
    Listofitems: ["Item 01", "Item 02", "Item 03"],
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    Title: "second title",
    Listofitems: ["Item 04", "Item 05", "Item 06"],
  },
];
```

...

```
const ModalList = ({ socket }) => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(null);

  const handleClose = () => setShow(null);
  const handleShow = (id) => setShow(id);

  ...

  return (
    <div className='container'>
      {lists.map(singleobject => (
        <div>
          <div>{singleobject.title}</div>
          <div>{singleobject.listofelement.join(', ')}</div>
          <div>
            <Button
              variant="primary"
              onClick={() => handleShow(singleobject.id)} // <-- pass id
            >
              {singleobject.title}
            </Button>
            <Modal
              show={show === singleobject.id} // <-- match id to show modal
              onHide={handleClose}
            >
              ....
            </Modal>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hey, thans for your answer. If i use your code an replace the `...` in the `<Modal>` tag with `{singleobject.title}` still the last object gets diplayed. Do I have to add something like init/define `singleobject` ?

Comment: @qwertzui It's entirely possible that this `Modal` component is using a single React portal. Could you create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the issue we could inspect live?

Comment: Oh it was my fault. I just copied your code without change `show === singleobject.is` to `show === singleobject.id` . I also added as you told a id to the `singleobject`. Works fine now thanks

Comment: @qwertzui Sorry for the typo. Great to hear you caught it and got your code working. I don't know how I completely missed that you'd included an example of your data. I've updated my answer to make adding an `id` property a little more overt. Glad to help, cheers and good luck!